# Evaluate once if string not in item when iterating over list - python 3.x

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, if-statement

I want to use this in an if statement so it would be useful if the output is a bollean expression but is there an easy way to find if string is not found in an item within a list?

e.g.

```
string_foo='teen'

list_foo=['one','two','three']
```

the problem is i need a loop to output somthing if a string is not found within an item in a list, the problem i have with doing it this way:

```
[print('no') if string_foo not in i for i in list_foo]
```

Is that for every item where string_foo isnt in i, it will print 'no' whereas i want it to only print 'no' once if string_foo isnt found within an item in list_foo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Don't use the side effects of list comprehensions

List comprehensions are to build new lists, not for their side effects. `print` returns `None`, so you are creating and discarding a list of `None` values. This is wasteful.

#### `any` / `all` + generator comprehension

One solution is to use `any` with a generator comprehension:

```
if not any(string_foo in i for i in list_foo):
    print('no')
```

Or equivalently with `all`:

```
if all(string_foo not in i for i in list_foo):
    print('no')
```

#### Write a function

Generators / generator expressions have overheads which you may find expensive. A regular function may be more efficient:

```
def any_in_list(mystr, lst):
    for i in lst:
        if mystr in i:
            return True
    return False

if not any_in_list(string_foo, list_foo):
    print('no')
```

#### `for` / `else` loop + `break`

If you don't want to write a generic function, you can replicate via a `for` / `else` construct with `break`:

```
for i in list_foo:
    if string_foo in i:
        break
else:
    print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. `list_foo` is only a list of strings so you don't need to loop over each item, you can just check to see if `string_foo` exists in the list or not.

```
if string_foo not in item:
  print('no')
```

Comment: But that isn't the same as searching for substrings.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```
if any(x in i for i in things):
    print("in it")
else:
    print("not in it")
```

The [any function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any) returns true if any of the list items is true.